# Linux crash with SPI in IRQ interrupt context

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, spi

I am writting a kernel platform driver which communicate with a MCU via SPI. The mcu triggers an gpio on the RPI which calls a IRQ function inside the kernel.  Then I write with "spi_sync" over SPI.
The IRQ function in linux looks like this:

```
static irqreturn_t vhub_irq(int irq, void *data)
{  
   disable_irq_nosync(irq);
   spin_lock_irqsave(&vhub->lock, flags);

   spi_sync(...);
   print_hex(vhub->transfer, 0x0f);

   spin_unlock_irqrestore(&vhub->lock, flags);
   enable_irq(irq);
}
```

IRQ is registered with

```
devm_request_irq(...)
```

The problem is that after 15 min. or so I get the following message and the system crashes:

```
Message from syslogd@pi3 at Feb 15 15:48:28 ...
 kernel:[ 1707.349069] 9320: ???????? ???????? ???????? ???????? ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
```

What is wrong with that?

Another question:

Is it necessary to disable the irq or is the irq disabled per default inside an IRQ?

Comment: Your code is **horribly broken**. First of all, you don't need to disable and re-enable IRQ explicitly, esp, in the IRQ handler. Second, you don't need to have `_irqsave()` / `_irqrestore()` spin locks. Third, you mustn't call sleeping functions in atomic (non-sleeping) context: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/spi/spi.c#L3857.

Comment: Say only what and why it is incorrect and let so things like "horribly broken"....

Comment: I see your appreciation, you see, it's quite okay to blame the code (not the person) and the code above is awful and I explained very well why.

Comment: I coming not that people say my code is broken. If the code isn't broken, I come not to stackoverflow. Emotional reaction is not the way to go.

Comment: 0andriy: It is your identification with your knowledge that you give comments in the way you do. You have a long way to go...

Comment: Interesting that you went down on the personal attacking instead of discussing the code. Maybe it’s not me here, who has issues?

Comment: I don't discuss with emotional people like you about coding.

Comment: Telling one story and putting an answer definitely based on my comments, Ookay. Good luck!

Comment: By far not. I found a document  "Interrupt Handling in Linux" from Valentin Rothberg. He explains it very well! 
Read it and sure you can get helpful information from there how something can be explained.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link!

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the following and it works fine with large and small spi data.

```
devm_request_threaded_irq
```

and

```
static irqreturn_t vhub_irq(int irq, void *data)
{  

    mutex_lock(&vhub->spi_bus_mutex);

    spi_sync(...);

    mutex_unlock(&vhub->spi_bus_mutex);
}
```